# Difference between adjectives and participle adjectives in english

Tags: participles

In the following sentence I have to identify participles.

> Michael, bereft of his son Luke, died of a broken heart.

I think there are 2 participles  ***bereft, broken***

But the answer was just ***bereft***

Comment: Note that this same sentence was asked about by the same poster in [this question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/206365/difference-between-adjectives-and-participle-adjectives/206366#206366) recently.  As mentioned there "broken" here is a "participle adjective" but it functions like any other adjective.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between adjectives and participle adjectives](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/206365/difference-between-adjectives-and-participle-adjectives)

Comment: broken is an adjective: broken heart, the adjectives are formed from past participles.

Comment: Broken is a participle adjective

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, I think you're correct. One might consider "broken" to be an adjective in its own right, but I definitely consider it a participle. In fact, as of this writing, it's the very first example on [the Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Participle):

> Participles have various uses in a sentence. One use of a participle is simply as an adjective: A broken window. A fallen tree. An interesting book.