# Difference between adjectives and participle adjectives

Tags: participles

> Michael, bereft of his son Luke, died of a **,broken*** heart.

Broken is adjective or participle adjective. I think it is participle adjective, because it is formed from the verb ***break***. But the book I am reading says it is not.

The same is the case with

> Lessons learned easily are soon ***fogotten***.

Answer (score 1):

You could call "broken" a "participle adjective". Certainly "broken" is derived from the verb "to break".

Note that a participle adjective is simply a category or sub-class of adjectives, they function in exactly the same way as all other adjectives, to modify nouns. I do not think that the distinction is very important. English very freely derives nouns from verbs, verbs from nouns, and adjectives from both.

[Your dictionary](https://grammar.yourdictionary.com/parts-of-speech/adjectives/what-is-a-participial-adjective.html) says:

> The participial adjectives are a major subclass of adjectives. They can be distinguished by their endings, usually either -ed or -ing. Some exceptions to the rules include misunderstood and unknown, which also function like these special adjectives. They are called participial adjectives because they have the same endings as verb participles.
>
> These adjectives are really meant to function like any other adjective: basically, they help to describe a noun. They might come from a verb form, or they might merely imitate the structure, but they always function as a descriptive adjective

An [article on ThoutCo](https://www.thoughtco.com/what-is-a-participial-adjective-1691486) says:

> Comparative and superlative forms of participial adjectives are formed with more and most and with less and least--not with the endings -er and -est.

This last difference (in how to form the comparative and superlative)  seems the only reason to even use the term, "participial adjective" or "verbal adjective"; otherwise an adjective is an adjective, whatever its form or source.

I would also note that "broken heart" is a set phrase, perhaps even an idiom. It is a metaphor, referring to the heart as the supposed seat of emotion, and a person with a broken heart is one devastated by grief or sadness, particularly for a lost love, but also from any other sad event. The term frequently occurs in popular song and verse, and has been in use for a very long time.